# MaybeEncodingError when returning large arrays with pool.starmap

Tags: python-multiprocessing

I'm experiencing a `MaybeEncodingError` when using `multiprocess` when the return list becomes too large.

I have a function that takes image as an input and produces a list of arrays as a result. Naturally data parallelization works magic in this case. I made a wrapper for running this in parallel, however I start receiving the `MaybeEncodingError` after reaching some threshold in memory when the results need to be merged with `pool.join()`. I decided to go with `pool` since the order of processing is very important.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def pool_starmap(function, input_list_tuple, processes = 5):
    with Pool(processes=processes) as pool:
        results = pool.starmap(function, input_list_tuple)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    return results

results=pool_starmap(function, input_list_tuple, processes=2)
```

I run the code on the server with 80 cores and 512GB of RAM. The whole code rarely exceeds 30GB and yet it breaks only for `pool`. How do I allow for returning the list of large arrays with `multiprocessing` but also preserving the order of execution?